# how to Get only 6 months from current month if year change after two months in bootstrap year calendar?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am stuck in bootstrap year calendar plugin please help me on this, currently i am stuck between a tiny thing that i want to enable only 6 months from the current month and other all months should be disabled and year changing should be working in that condition but i didn't get any way to enable only 6 months from the current month because when user change year from the header my custom script is stop working. please help me on this. i am posting my code

to create calendar i am using

$('#calendar').calendar();

and to open a modal on click of a day i am using this script. but whenever year is changed from the header my below script stop working.

```
$(".day-content").click(function(){
    $('#confirm_modal').modal('show');
});
```

You can create your own calendar via download the example from the link and by creating a simple div with id of calendar.

http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Download

Thank you in advance

Comment: A `document.write` in the script? Please show the code, it's hard to debug a code you can't see.

Comment: Hii teemu thanks for your reply.

http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/Full example

this is the link from which i get the bootstrap year calendar code

Comment: In the question itself. The equestion will be useless to the future readers, when you fix the issue in your source code.